# Pintar linhas da DBGrid ao selecioná-las

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, dbgrid

Estou pintando as linhas de uma [dbgrid](/questions/tagged/dbgrid), no [delphi-xe3](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe3), porém minha condição para pintar a linha selecionada não está funcionando corretamente.

Ao selecionar a linha (setar o foco) somente a primeira coluna está sendo pintada. Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo da DBGrid com a linha selecionada]

A propriedade `Options`, `dgRowSelect` está setada como `True`.

Meu código para pintar as linhas e pintar a linha quando está selecionada, conforme encontrado nos exemplo pela web:

```delphi
procedure TFrmCadTerminal.dbgTerminaisDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  inherited;
  if cdsTerminal.IsEmpty then exit;

  if cdsTerminalAcess_TerE.AsString <> 'S' then
  begin
    if gdFocused in State then
    begin
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      dbgTerminais.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field, State);
    end
    else
    begin
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Brush.Color := clMaroon;
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      dbgTerminais.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field, State);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Gostaria que toda a linha fosse pintada da mesma cor ao selecioná-la.
Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```delphi
procedure TFrmCadLicenca.dbgTerminaisDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  inherited;
  if cdsTerminal.IsEmpty then exit;

  if cdsTerminalAcess_TerE.AsString <> 'S' then
  begin
    if (gdSelected in State) and dbgTerminais.Focused then
    begin
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      dbgTerminais.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field, State);
    end
    else
    begin
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Brush.Color := clMaroon;
      dbgTerminais.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
      dbgTerminais.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Column.Field, State);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Aconselho a testar com o `and` adicional, o `dbgTerminais.Focused`.

Comment: Valeu pela dica, me livrou o dia.